# "Use this Page as a Page Type" - How to give non-Admin users permission to set this property

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

The non-Admin users are not able to create new Pages using option “Use this Page as a Page Type”, because it is disabled for them at a Page level.

There is no specific right associated in SDL Tridion for this, and an admin only function now. We have below link as reference for setting/enabling this:

[Online Documentation - Enabling the creation of new Web pages](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_C87299D47BC94982B238BA547A4B4A76) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

How can we give non-Admin users the rights to mark a page as a Page-Type?

Can anyone give us suggestions on enabling this for Non-Admin users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, all Experience Manager settings are only modifiable by a user with System Administration rights. This is purely a UI trick, as the CM core itself will not enforce this rule.

The decision was taken to do it like this during XPM development due to added complexity of adding one more right to Tridion and investment in training, etc. Experience Manager is already complicated enough to set up, adding one more security layer would not make it simpler. The downside of it is that in secure Tridion environments you probably need to open a ticket to get someone to click on that checkbox.

We are currently investigating changing this so that it is a bit more user-friendly and requiring less Admin intervention, but it will probably not come soon enough for you. The only alternatives you have right now go through creating a custom extension that would set the same values (this information is stored in the page's Application Data) and Experience Manager would pick it up from there. Or, if it would make it easier, you could create a custom page instead and give users some sort of page list with check-boxes to turn the selected pages into page types or something along those lines.

Comment: what is the latest update on this with SDL Web8 upgrade? Can we now make this non admin functionality?

Comment: SDL Web 8.5 does introduce quite a few more layers in permissions - there's a new "Publication Administrator" right giving users admin permissions within given publications, and there's also a set of new privileges. Not sure how broad we went with this specific setting, but certainly a "Publication Administrator" can modify this now.

Comment: certainly == I hope